# Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома

Tags: java, xml, парсер, исключения, dom

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как указать путь к файлу чтобы он не ругался? 
***FileNotFoundException***

```
public boolean changeValuesInFiles() {
            for (File f : newFilesList) {
                try {
                    String filepath = "file:///"+f.getAbsolutePath();
                    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

                    Node pointOfSale = doc.getElementsByTagName("PointOfSale").item(0);

                    NamedNodeMap attr = pointOfSale.getAttributes();
                    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("PointOfSaleCode");
                    nodeAttr.setTextContent("999");
                    nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("ParentPointOfSale");
                    nodeAttr.setTextContent("999");

                    pointOfSale = doc.getElementsByTagName("PointOfSaleDescription").item(0);
                    attr = pointOfSale.getAttributes();
                    nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("Description");
                    nodeAttr.setTextContent("999");

                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
                    transformer.transform(source, result);

                    return true;

                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: а нельзя вместо вот этого `Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);` написать вот это `Document doc = docBuilder.parse(f);` ?

Comment: получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо передачи пути к файлу

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

Передайте сам объект файла

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(f);
```